# Http Post multiple parameters with file

Tags: android, post, apache-httpcomponents

I have seen multiple ways to send a file using HttpPost. 
However, to send a file and other text parameters always seems to require the MultipartEntity object which is in the Apache Http components API.

In the version 4.3, **MultipartEntity is deprecated**

I have been looking in the documentation, without finding another solution to post multipart data. Either have I here.

I really don't want to use a deprecated object.
Any hints?

Comment: deprecated doesn't mean it doesn't work

Comment: "A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists.". So yes, it works. But I don't think it is suitable for a production environnement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, deprecated annotation are accompanied by a note explaining what to use instead. In this case :

```
Class MultipartEntity
(...)
Deprecated. 
4.3 Use MultipartEntityBuilder.
```

Which is documented here : http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how I missed it.